# Can I have public repo with private files with free account?

Tags: github

I like to have issues open to public but private files. It is possible with free version of github ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. You can only have private repositories on paid or student plans.

Additionally, you can't have issues set to public and sourcecode set to private. Read more at https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issues-only-repository/

Comment: Oh, i see. Do you know about alternative hosting where is this possible ?